# Filtering nosetests by numeric range

Tags: python, nosetests

All of my nosetests are of the form:

```
def test_555():    chk(555); do_some_testing(...)
def test_556():    chk(556); some_more_testing()
```

The chk() function will check to see if that test number is one that I am currently wanting to execute -- this is my own ignore-test logic based on numeric ranges.  this function simply raises:  unittest.SkipTest()   to skip a test.

I am happy with this setup, but I would like to somehow auto decorate ALL of my tests in a way that I automatically derive the 'chk(i)' check for each test.  I cannot see how to obtain the currently executing test object, during the test itself, nor how to somehow auto decorate all tests.

but maybe there is a better way?  My goal to be able to update :

```
RUN_TESTS = (590,720)
```

in my source code, and have the correct thing happen

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nose-parametarized](https://github.com/wolever/nose-parameterized) is your friend:

```
from nose_parameterized import parameterized

def chk(number):
    print number

@parameterized.expand([[x, x] for x in range(100)])
def test(_, number):
    chk(number)
```

Running tests:

```
$ nosetests pr.py
pr.test_0 ... ok
pr.test_1 ... ok
...
pr.test_98 ... ok
pr.test_99 ... ok
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 100 tests in 0.078s

OK
```

Selecting tests:

```
$ nosetests pr.py:test_89 -v -s
pr.test_89 ... 89
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

Comment: Well I am going to count this as correct, since it may well work for most people.  My goal is to keep each of my tests distinct, since I like to put a break-point at the beginning of the failing test, in order to debug.  If I build a multi-page tuple of tests, I don't think I can do that -- though I guess I could configure it to only run the one test.  Still thanks. --dan

Comment: `nosetests --pdb` and `nosetests --pdb-failure` are your other friends. To trigger break-point in the code above, just add `if number == 45: set_trace()`